# stem-and-leaf plot

Tags: tables

I have the following MWE to generate a Stem-and-leaf plot.
I have included a pdf of the output.
I would like the word Stem to appear above the stem on the plot; and the word leaf to appear avove the leaves. At the moment the text "Stem" is too far to the right.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,english]{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\caption{Key: $1 | 1= 1.1$}
\begin{tabular}{r|l@{\hspace{4 pt}}l@{\hspace{4 pt}}l@{\hspace{4 pt}}l@{\hspace{4 pt}}l@{\hspace{4 pt}}l@{\hspace{4 pt}}l@{\hspace{4 pt}}l@{\hspace{4 pt}}l@{\hspace{4 pt}}}
\multicolumn{9}{l}{} Stem & Leaf     \\     \hline     1     & 1     & 1     & 2     & 3     & 3     & 4     & 4     &       &  \\         1     & 5     & 6     & 6     & 8     &       &       &       &       &  \\         2     & 0     & 3     &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\         2     & 7     & 8     &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\         3     &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\         3     & 5     & 7     & 8     & 8     &       &       &       &       &  \\     4     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 1     & 2     & 4     & 4     & 4     &  \\     4     & 5     & 5     & 6     & 7     & 7     & 7     & 8     & 8     & 9 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
Stem & \multicolumn{8}{l}{ Leaf}
```

instead of:

```
\multicolumn{9}{l}{} Stem & Leaf
```